# .js file with just a require([" "," ",..., function(){}]) inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, requirejs

My question is about the use of "require" statement JavaScript.
I'm starting working with JS and Dojo and I've the following issue:

I'm developing a Plug-in for a web site and the main Java class of the plugin make a reference through the main web application API. A .js

```
public String getScript() {
    return "SampleSearchChoiceListPlugin.js";
}
```

This SampleSearchChoiceListPlugin.js has just a require, with an array of paths and a function that overrides two functions inside its body. (The code of the functions is not listed because I think this is irrelevant). It has the following content:

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare",
         "dojo/_base/lang",
         "ecm/widget/SinglePropertyEditorFactory",
         "sampleSearchChoiceListPluginDojo/SearchChoicePane"
         ],function(declare, lang, SinglePropertyEditorFactory, SearchChoicePane) {     
    /* Use this function to add any global JavaScript methods your plug-in requires.*/
    SinglePropertyEditorFactory.prototype.createSinglePropertyEditor = function(kwArgs) {
         },
    SinglePropertyEditorFactory.prototype._createSearchChoiceListEditor = function(baseConstraints, kwArgs) {

    };
});
```

SampleSearchChoiceListPlugin.js is being loaded in the target web application because Firebug is recognizing the script. I set some breakpoints on the the ProImageLayoutPlugin.js I checked that this JavaScript is not being run or triggered by any of the actions that are supposed to trigger this.

I'm new to development with JS and it would be great if anyone could explain to me how these "require" scripts work or lead me to a link in where this is explained? I read that this could be something related to requirejs but not sure...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dojo, `require` is an AMD loader. You can think of it as a way of importing modules, similarly to the `import` statement in Java and Python (et al.).

- The first argument is an array of strings, which are the paths to the modules you want to load.
- The second argument is a function callback, which names each of the modules you specified in the module array. In general, if the first array has `n` elements, this function should take `n` arguments.

Inside your function callback, you can use the modules. Keep in mind that they are scoped, so outside this function, these modules are not accessible.

Here's an example of code run from a `require` statement, which creates a button that alerts "Hello, world!" when it is clicked:

```
require([
    'dijit/form/Button', 
    'dojo/on', 
    'dojo/dom', 
    'dojo/dom-construct'
], function(Button, on, dom, domConstruct) {
    var btn = new Button({ label: 'Hello!' });
    on(btn, 'click', function(e) {
        alert('Hello, world!');
    });
    domConstruct.place(dom.byId('someNodeID'), btn.domNode);
});
```

If you want your plugin to run, you need to turn it into a module. Fortunately, this is pretty simple to do with `define`, which is similar to `require`, except it is used to create a module (think, "class") instead of just to define the necessary components for a block of code. Here's an example from the **[DojoToolkit reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modules/)**:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/dom",
    "app/dateFormatter"
], function(declare, dom, dateFormatter) {
    return declare(null, {
        showDate: function(id, date){
            dom.byId(id).innerHTML = dateFormatter.format(date);
        }
    });
});
```

This defines a module that has a public `showDate` function. You can structure your plugin similarly and call it in the module you load it into.

Answer (score 0):

The `require` is not a part of regular JavaScript but is rather part of an `AMD` module.

From the particular syntax I'm guessing that you are looking at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)